# Skipping some part in compiling

Tags: compiling

Is it possible to compile file including section, text, figures and equation in a way of skipping text? I would like to have a choice:

compile everything

compile only equations, sections and figures without captions

The structure of file is from input commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}


\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's an [almost identical question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513329/82917) from one week ago, though admittedly (and, to be honest, somewhat unsurprisingly) it hasn't had any answer yet.

Comment: I saw this question in similar question to my, but it doesn't help because it is not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to exclude all normal text is to use `\nullfont`, though I'm not sure whether you'll like this, and it would only skip the text that doesn't have any font changes in it:

```latex
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\nullfont
\chapter{This Chapter Heading}
This text \emph{emphasized}
\section{This Section Heading}
This text
\begin{figure}% >>=
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      This caption%
      \label{fig:duck}%
    }%
\end{figure}% =<<
This text
\subsection{This Subsection Heading}
This text
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how to deal with math mode in text and lists?

Comment: @LukášAltman that'd be much more complicated, you'd have to redefine the environments to not do anything, and for in text maths you could abuse `\everymath`, all in all I guess it'd be easier to write an extern script that extracts those blocks from the file.

Comment: Thank you very much